# ElasticBeanStalk instance fails unrecoverably after adding .config file in .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

The deployment of an EBS instance fails after trying to add a .config file inside .ebextensions directory.
The file is named 01commands.config and has the following content:

```
container_commands:
  collectstatic:
    command: "echo Test!"
    leader_only: true
```

The Events section in the instance console shows the following message:
"Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'XXXX'. Aborting the operation."

Any clues of what can be happening or how can I access some kind of log for instances with a severe status?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is the quotes around the command.

Should be:

`command: echo "Test!"`